# residue integral for specific range of a

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I know for $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{1+a cos\theta}  $ where $-1<a<1$, we take a c: unit circle as the contour and change the integrand into a rational function and then apply the residue theorem.

Now I reached to $\int_c \frac{-2i}{az^2+z+a}dz\  $

 the singularities of integrand then are: $z=\frac{-1+\sqrt{}1-4a^2}{2}$ and $z=\frac{-1-\sqrt{}1-4a^2}{2}$. I am stuck here.  what is the next step? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Small suggestion: Why don't you first pick a value for $a$ and work that out. See where the numbers "flow" and then generalize it.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{1+a\cos \theta} = \frac{2}{i} \oint \frac{dz}{az^2 +2z+a}$$ where the contour is the unit circle taken counter-clockwise.

The poles occur at $z_{1,2}=-\frac{1}{a} \pm \frac{\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a}.$

The pole $z_{1}=\frac{\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a}-\frac{1}{a}$ is inside the circle.  Compute the residue there!

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{1+a\cos \theta} = \frac{2}{ia} \cdot 2\pi i \cdot \textrm{Res}_{z=z_1}\left[ \frac{1}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}\right]= \frac{4\pi}{a} \cdot \frac{1}{(z_1-z_2)}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$$